# SOAPFaultException when deployed on Tomcat but works fine in GlassFish

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-ws, glassfish-3, tomcat7

Friends, I have been trying a lot and read many forums but unable to understand why this issue is coming up.
I created a Jax-WS WebService using contract first approach. Created WSDL & XSD and then used wsimport tool to generate rest of the artifacts, provided implementation for  SEI.

Deployed the WebService application to GlassFish in Eclipse Helios (Glassfish adapter and plugin installed in Eclipse). Tested the deployed service through SoapUI and it works fine.

I deployed this web service into Tomcat7.0 as a WAR file. Structure as:

```
WAR -> META-INF -> MANIFEST.MF

    -> WEB-INF -> classes -> ...

               -> wsdl -> .wsdl and .xsd

               -> web.xml

               -> sun-jaxws.xml
```

When I test the webservice through SoapUI, the response I get is an exception as:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://localhost/fundmanagertd}addFund but found: {http://localhost/fundmanagertd}requestAddFund</faultstring>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I think it is working in Glassfish because Glassfish is generating all the artifacts on the fly and not accepting the ones which are already generated. While Tomcat is taking only those which are in the deployed package. Why I think so, because web services work in Glassfish only when sun-jaxws.xml is not provided, but when it is provided I am not able to see the service under "Deployed Service" section. While Tomcat uses sun-jasws.xml and uses the classes I have provided and fails. I don't know why this is happening. Any direction from here would be much appreciated.

WSDL I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="http://localhost/fundmanagertd" name="FundManagerTDService" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost/fundmanagertd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://localhost/fundmanagertd" schemaLocation="FundManagerTDService_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="addFund">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:requestAddFund"/>
  </message>
  <message name="addFundResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:responseAddFund"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="Fund">
    <operation name="addFund">
      <input message="tns:addFund"/>
      <output message="tns:addFundResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="FundPortBinding" type="tns:Fund">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="addFund">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Add"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="FundManagerTDService">
    <port name="FundPort" binding="tns:FundPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

FundManagerTDService_schema1.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://localhost/fundmanagertd" xmlns:tns="http://localhost/fundmanagertd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="requestAddFund" type="tns:requestAddFund"/>

  <xs:element name="responseAddFund" type="tns:responseAddFund"/>

  <xs:complexType name="fund">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="annuity" type="tns:annuityType" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="duration" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="endDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="premium" type="xs:float"/>
      <xs:element name="startDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="type" type="tns:investmentType" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="value" type="xs:float"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="requestAddFund">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="arg0" type="tns:fund" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="arg1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="responseAddFund">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="xs:long"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="annuityType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="MONTHLY"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="investmentType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="MF"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

SoapUI is generating request automatically and it is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fun="http://localhost/fundmanagertd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fun:requestAddFund>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <annuity>?</annuity>
            <duration>?</duration>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <endDate>?</endDate>
            <id>?</id>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <name>?</name>
            <premium>?</premium>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <startDate>?</startDate>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <type>?</type>
            <value>?</value>
         </arg0>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg1>?</arg1>
      </fun:requestAddFund>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Also, I have tried creating a static client to access my web service and I get SOAPFaultException with "unexpected XML tag message..."

Also, adding sun-jaxws.xml for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
  version="2.0">
  <endpoint
      name="fundmanagertdservice"
      implementation="com.investment.webservice.impl.FundManagerService"
      url-pattern="/fundmanagertdsvr"
      wsdl="WEB-INF/wsdl/FundManagerTDService.wsdl"/>
</endpoints>
```

Thanks,

Comment: This is a very thorough question already, but could you add the SOAP UI request as well?  Also, was the request built automatically in SOAP UI or did you write the XML yourself? Thanks!

Comment: Hi derdc, Thanks for giving it a look. I have added some more details above.

Comment: When you tested it in glassfish SoapUi created exactly the same xml?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first element in the SOAP request Body needs to be the operations that you are calling.
This means that the auto-generated XML needs to be changed. This is exactly what the error are saying:

> ...expected:
>
> ...addFund - method name - but found:
>
> ...requestAddFund - data type name